# CosmosDB transactions per partition

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am looking at CosmosDB partitioning facility and what I have got so far is that it is good for performance. It can really help us in avoiding the fanout queries but I have got stuck into one question with partitioning. For partitioning in write if I have got different type of documents, can be thousands of them, belong to same partition the write operation will be slow but if I give them different partition key then I will lose the transactional behaviour because store procedures are scoped to one transaction.

My use case is I have got different type of documents within same collection and at one given time i will be updating and inserting thousands of different type of documentation and I have to do that within the same transaction which means I have to use the same key but if I do that then I will be doing HOT write operation which is not suggested in CosmosDB. Anyhelp on how to achive this issue will be be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People use stored procedures to batch their documents and today it does constrain you to one partition. However, be aware of other limitations that your partition key should be as such that your documents fan out in different partitions. So your one batch can be for one partition key and next batch is for another.

read more here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data

hope this help.

Rafat

Comment: Hi Rafat, Thanks for the prompt reply here. I got what u saying but just to clarification i will give u one example to help me understanding it better. i have got two partition let say one for city and one for country. If i update or insert country as one batch and city as once batch, as u have mentioned, I think it will not be wrapped up in one transaction or is it? but if i create just one tenannt partition for both city and country then I can warp them under one transaction but still that request has to be completed in one batch isn't it?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  Two partitions means two transactions.  Perhaps consider a compound key of "country:city" that would give you a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Its tricky.. I do have a large set of docs within a single partition at the moment, maybe later on I would need to redesign the collection. Right now I am using a bulk insert/update lib in CosmosDB. Link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-overview  Way faster for large data inserts/updates, its Microsoft backed library, however it supports transactional behaviour but only withing a single partition. So at the moment, I am safe.